# Finding multi dimensional array value that doesnt match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multi dimensional arrays. Both arrays are almost identical except one of them has a value that doesn't exist in the other. The arrays I"m working with are:

Array1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => BeS712210
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => De 48245
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => All50481
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Bis1016338
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => S-T41471
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Ron35844
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Lin10961
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Tip295926
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => SLN893827
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Fen1016241
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Aut331661
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Pro39613
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Com920158
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Sma21322
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Bev121157
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Cit3043324
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Que2182100
        )

)
```

Array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => BeS712210
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => De 48245
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => All50481
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Bis1016338
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => S-T41471
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Ron35844
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Lin10961
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Tip295926
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => SLN893827
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Fen1016241
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Aut331661
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Pro39613
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Com920158
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Sma21322
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Bev121157
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Que2182100
        )

)
```

The value that doesnt match:

```
[16] => Array
    (
        [dexcode] => Cit3043324
    )
```

With PHP I tried to get the value that doesnt match like this:

```
$a1 =array_unique($all_codes,SORT_REGULAR);

$a2 =array_unique($matches,SORT_REGULAR);

$results = check_diff_multi($a1, $a2);

function check_diff_multi($array1, $array2){
    $results = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
         if(isset($array2[$key])){
           if(is_array($val) && $array2[$key]){
               $result[$key] = check_diff_multi($val, $array2[$key]);
           }
       } else {
           $results[$key] = $val;
       }
    }

    return array_unique($results,SORT_REGULAR);
}
```

$a1 is the first array that I posted above which contains the different value.
$a2 is the second one.

the different values should be added to the $results variable.

When i check what's in $results like this:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($results);
print '</pre>';
```

I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
        (
            [dexcode] => Que2182100
        )

)
```

It seems to pick the last value only. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Your `if(is_array($val) && $array2[$key]){` condition looks strange to me: shouldn't it be `if(is_array($val) && is_array($array2[$key])){`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) functions

```
$arr1 = array_column($arr1, 'dexcode');
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, 'dexcode');
print_r(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19419c10379c399d1e34f6d281933358d5f4d3b7)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so much shorter.